# $_POST does not update value

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Currently trying to update a defined value with a form but it does not work for me.
I did try several things even a function that updates the value with a +1 that works on another page so I am not sure what the problem with my form is.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submitcounter'])){
function mail_counter(){
    $val = $_POST['test']; //Increment the current count
    update_option(CF7_COUNTER, $val); //Update the settings with the new count
}
}


/*
function update_counter(){
update_option(CF7_COUNTER, (int) $_POST['test']);
}
*/

?>

<h1>Settings Page</h1>

<form method="post" action="" >

    <label for="Settings_text">Settings</label>

    <input type="number" name="test" value="<?php echo get_option(CF7_COUNTER); ?>"/> 
    <input type="submit" name="submitcounter" value="update"  class="button button-primary button-large">
</form>
```

The idea is for the function to replace the existing value ( whatever it may be 42 or 10209) with the input of the form.

Comment: You are not calling function the defined function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submitcounter']))
    {
        // Update the settings with the new count
        update_option(CF7_COUNTER, $_POST['test']);
    }

?>

<h1>Settings Page</h1>

<form method="post" action="" >

    <label for="Settings_text">Settings</label>

    <input type="number" name="test" value="<?=get_option(CF7_COUNTER);?>"/> 
    <input type="submit" name="submitcounter" value="update"  class="button button-primary button-large">
</form>
```

Removed code not required and improved the readability of the code.

Comment: You're welcome! If this does indeed answer your issue, could you mark it as being answered. :)

Comment: Of course could you tel where I can mark this as finished is not really in a obvious place.

Comment: I would probably do `if(isset($_POST['submitcounter']) && isset($_POST['test'])){}` to be sure to catch that potential error

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the function as code is written in function body and control is not going there:

```
if (isset($_POST['submitcounter'])) {
 function mail_counter(){
  $val = $_POST['test']; //Increment the current count
  //Update the settings with the new count
  update_option(CF7_COUNTER, $val);    
 }
 mail_counter(); // This function is defined but not called.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must remove mail_counter() function

Comment: Thanks ^ I copied a certain example and didnt think about that